# Libinput touchpad problems

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, libinput

Hi guys i am using ubuntu 16.04 I am facing issues with the touchpad, i am using libinput. 
1) By default the tap to click is disabled.I have to manually enable it everytime using xinput set-prop option. There's an option to enable by default, but i am getting this error

input: xinput set-prop 13 296 1
output: X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

2) the pointer jumps whenever i want it to be a particular place. For example if i want to check on the check box it jumps some where else.If i want to close or minimize a windows it will jump somewhere else. It jumps whenever i release my finger.

3) there is no touchpad option in settings.

And please don't tell me to install synaptics which is much worse than libinput. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf** with root priviliges (sudo) before the EndSection marker: `Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"`
2. Add `Option "Tapping" "1"` or `Option "Tapping" "true"`
3. Reboot

Comment: You could suggest edit to fix a typo. This is not a real answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can enable tapping in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf` by
adding

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

to the touchpad section of the file before `EndSection`.

3) The GUI does not support `libinput` options yet.

The 2) issue is a bug of some sort and is probably hardware specific.

I suggest asking a new question about this issue adding the output of `xinput` terminal command. And even better is to report it to Launchpad as a bug.